# Don't apply a middleware to a specific route

Tags: laravel

I want a piece of middleware to apply to all routes in a group, except for one route. Can I specify on the route that the middleware should not be applied?

Comment: Yes, you can; in the Middleware though, not the route. That being said, what have you tried so far? What issues are you facing? What's not working?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I want the globally applied `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware to not be applied to one route. I can move it out of the global stack, but I really want it there, except for one route. I didn't see anything in the docs about this...

Comment: A quick Google search for "Ignore Route from Middleware" turns up a lot... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes for example. And if you haven't tried anything, that's where you need to start; Stackoverflow is not for having code written for you; it's for when you encounter *specific issues*.

Answer (score 0):

Route groups are a means of applying the same configuration to all routes they contain. I understand you want to share most of the middleware configuration with all your routes except one. You can use **nested route groups** to make most of that config shared.

The following should do the trick for you:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['a', 'b', 'c']], function () {
    Route::get('route1_with_3_middlewares', 'MyController@test');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'd'], function () {
        Route::get('route2_with_4_middlewares', 'MyController@test');
        Route::get('route3_with_4_middlewares', 'MyController@test');
        Route::get('route4_with_4_middlewares', 'MyController@test');
    });
});
```

This way you have middlewares **a**, **b** and **c** applied to all routes and middleware **d** applied to all routes except the first one.